# How to detect changes in a muti list box using jquery

Tags: jquery

Using the code below I am able to add and remove elements using the add'remove buttons.Now Im trying to detect changes when a change occurs in any of these list boxes.How do i go about doing that using jQuery?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#btn-add').click(function(){
        $('#select-from option:selected').each( function() {
                $('#select-to').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });
    $('#btn-remove').click(function(){
        $('#select-to option:selected').each( function() {
            $('#select-from').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: @iambriansreed although your comment may be accurate, there are much nicer ways of saying it.

Comment: lol @iambriansreed. why RTFM when you can go on stackoverflow...free points! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like youre adding options dynmically, but you would only need to watch change events in the select's themselves..

so you could add

```
//jquery 1.7.1
$('#select-to').on('change', function(){});
$('#select-from').on('change', function(){});
```

to monitor a selection change...if you want to follow the event of the options being added, you could do that in the click event of the button that also adds/removes the options.

Comment: thanks for ur answer mate.The above only trigger when the select element gets focus.What I am trying to achieve is to trigger a function as soon as any update[add/delete] occurs on the list boxes.

Comment: like I say, you just have to add more to your $('#btn-add').click(function(){}); call

Comment: the change happens when you add/remove, that is the trigger for the change ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do

```
$('#select-to').change(function() {
    //your onChange code here
});
$('#select-from').change(function() {
    //your onChange code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom event

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('#btn-add').click(function(){
        $('#select-from option:selected').each( function() {
                $('#select-to').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
                $('#select-to,#select-from').trigger('customchange');
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });
    $('#btn-remove').click(function(){
        $('#select-to option:selected').each( function() {
            $('#select-from').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
            $('#select-to,#select-from').trigger('customchange');
            $(this).remove();
       });
    });
});
```

then bind any function to that event:

```
$('#select-to').bind('customchange', function(){
  //do whatever
});
```